# PostgreSQL: Prevent SQL injection for like query with % input

Tags: postgresql, query

We are allowing the user to post the contents on our application, in a case user entered the `%` in the title of the post and we are running like query to fetch the data from the database.
Here is the snippet from the post table

```
id |         title           | short_description |   long_description
 1   how many % amounts you       ----------          --------------
     should save                --------------       -----------------
```

Query we are running:

```
SELECT id, title from post where post.title LIKE '%string entered by user%'
```

Now if the user enters `amounts` then query works fine and returns something like.

```
SELECT id, title from post where post.title LIKE '%amounts%'
```

and returning the desired result.

But, when a user enters `how many % amounts` in the search field, it is returning all the rows which are starting from `how many` and contains `amounts` in the upcoming words, which is wrong because the generated query is.

```
SELECT id, title from post where post.title LIKE '%how many % amounts%'
```

And another thing is if the user enters only `%` the query returns all the results.

If we try escaping the `%` or other special characters and the result is way more different than it should be.

Please suggest a solution if you have any.

Comment: @Colin'tHart using `sequelize` ORM for PostgreSQL with NodeJS. And can you please explain, how replacing % with %% can overcome the situation?

Comment: @Colin'tHart nope! not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Quoting the like expression

The percent or underscore characters in the user-supplied string must be quoted as [documented](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html#LIKE):

> To match a literal underscore or percent sign without matching other
>   characters, the respective character in pattern must be preceded by
>   the escape character. The default escape character is the backslash
>   but a different one can be selected by using the ESCAPE clause. To
>   match the escape character itself, write two escape characters.

For instance:

If the user submits `ab%`, the code must do:

```
where title like '%ab#%%' escape '#';
```

Be aware that the user might submit a string with your escape character in it.
For this reason it has to be escaped itself. If for instance the user submits `abc%def#`, the code must do:

```
where title like '%abc#%def##%' escape '#';
```

### Using strpos

Another solution is to check the result of `strpos` instead of using `LIKE` to find if a substring is in a larger string. `strpos` does not have wildcards characters and returns a non-zero number if the substring is found.

```
select strpos('abcdef', 'cd') > 0 ;
 ?column? 
----------
 t
```

`strpos` also uses the [Boyer Moore Horspool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore%E2%80%93Horspool_algorithm)  algorithm which be faster in some cases, especially since PostgresQL 12 where it applies it directly to UTF-8 contents without converting them first to wide chars internally.

Comment: That worked like a charm!

Comment: This doesn't answer the question IMO.  SQL injection requires quoting the ' to avoid breaking out of the string!

Comment: @user239558: even though the asker mentioned "SQL injection" in the title, that's not what the question is about. It's asking how to neutralize wildcards characters in the argument following LIKE.